# Session times out soon before set Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that apparently keeps timing out before the Set Period.

My Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login/Login" slidingExpiration="false" timeout="60" protection="All"></forms>
</authentication>
```

I have tried changing the Session state from IIS but the set time is not respected.

Session State settings

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login/Login" slidingExpiration="false"
        timeout="60" protection="All"></forms>
</authentication>
<compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" />
```

Comment: Do you see the cookie time setting up properly in the response ?

Comment: Pardon your question

Comment: Can you show your Session state settings please, from your web config?

Comment: You need to find the reason first. Long time back my friend was facing a very similar issue, We change session to outproc state server (temporary) then his app was working fine. later we found IIS app pool was getting restart due to memory leak issue. You can check IIS logs.